# Automated User INput

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to prompt the user for input, and Get the input from a Predefined set of values

```
echo Please Enter a Name
echo.
set /p a=name:
echo.
echo welcome  %a%
```

This would Actually working if I give input in the console . But what i need is after I give the original command , the value should be auto populated.  I tried

```
sleep/waitfor
```

etc but even without giving input in Console the next line in the batch script is not going to get executed.

Comment: The Windows command interpreter is not DOS.

Comment: @AndrewMedico true that !

Comment: @Noodles The idea was not to give user any choice , rather automatically put the choice as "pre Hardcoded". so After Please enter a name- and the cursor blinking _ , the value should be auto populated .

Comment: `if not defined %a% set a=cat`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this ?

```
@echo off
echo Please Enter a Name
echo.
set /p a=name:
echo.
echo welcome  %a% 
pause
```

Comment: Well the pause button does not automatically takes the input from the user.so what i want is the console to take the automated input as a name say "JOHN" after the command "Please enter a name" .

Comment: in command line when you ask user his name , unless you write some thing in the terminal console and press Enter, it aint gonna take anything from anywhere else ( like automated reading from some file , or even your next line in the script), it is something like waiting for user input through Keyborad . so that I need to be automated somehow .